# C# ConnectionString

Tags: c#, .net

How can I use the connectionString defined in APP.Config in datasource wizard?
I can do it in a web application easily but I can't do it in non web application program.

Comment: You can copy temporary the .config file in some app_data/ directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the bellow syntax to retrive the connection string from app.config

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Then use the bellow syntax.Oh!first of all you need to add **using System.Configuration;** name space

```
 Connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I use it in DataSource configuration wizard, in "which data connection should you application use to connecto to dabase" part, my mean is in design not in run time

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with ConfigurationManager class.
This should do:

```
string myConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnStringName"].ConnectionString;
```